# Asus MB memory error after turning on the computer

Tags: memory, motherboard

This is my pc's specs

Asus-Z87-PLUS (latest bios and drivers)

Core i5 4570

Crucial 8Gig DDR3 @1600 compatible with Intel's 8th series chip

WD caviar green 1TB

Sapphire ATI 7850 (latest drivers)

850W Memonex power supply

windows 8.1 x64

i get this error every time i turn on my pc: "the memory address is insufficient due to intel thunderbolt resource consumption". i've tried to reinstall my windows, install all new drivers. i've also reset clock settings back to their defaults but the error still exists.

i also get this error usually in windows specially when i'm working with browsers and photoshop:"amd display driver has stopped responding and has recovered" and explorer.exe resets. but sometimes this error leads to a restart and screen goes black and stays like that. i just wanted to say that i have that error too, that's not the main question because after uninstalling catalyst control center it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note the following 2 cases where people have the similar problem:

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2011144/problem-graphics-card-work.html#12605163

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-2027152/asus-z87-pro-thunderbolt-error-weird-behaviour.html

The first case was a faulty MB, please check with Asus support.

Comment: i read those articles and my MB doesn't have any problem. i gotta say that this error appears more after i connected my 2nd cpu fan plug to its specified place. before that it was plugged to somewhere else in MB because the wire was too short.when it was not connected to the default place i got this error every month, not like this every day.